# Relative localisation of 3d planar lines and points

Tags: geometry

Let $E$ be a set of 3D planar points, let's call this plane $P$ defined by a normal vector $\vec{n}$ and a point $B$. We also define $L$ a line defined by two points $S_0$ and $S_1$, two points in plane $P$.

The goal is to find how many elements of $E$ are on one side of $L$ or the other.

**This is how I do it**, but the results seems to not be correct but the maths seems ok. Can you confirm it ?

I'm computing the normal vector of the orthogonal plane of $P$ by calculating the cross product of $\vec{n}$ and the vector $\vec{S_0 S_1}$. So :

$$\vec{n_l} = \vec{S_0 S_1} \times \vec{n} $$

Then I iterate over my set of point $E$, and compute for each element $e_i$:

$$ result_i=sign(\vec{S_0 e_1} \cdot \vec{n}) $$

Then I count how many $result_i$ are positives and deduces the negatives count. If they are all positives or all negatives, they are on the same side of the line.

---

$L$ over the set $E$. So $L$ is not random.

Comment: Based on your description, it seems to be right. From your phrasing, you think your implementation is wrong? What makes you think your results are wrong?

Comment: Thanks @N.Bach. It seems wrong because visually I can see when all the points are on the same side of the line but it's not what is happening. So I expecting a math error. I was thinking maybe choosing $S_o$ is not the best. Maybe I have to choose a point not on the line ?

Comment: (Probable) typos aside, the approach you presented should work. I could go over the geometric interpretation of the elements you compute if that can help you. To proceed further in the discussion, it would be good if you could provide a minimum example: a small collection of points $E$ and the two points defining $L$. And maybe the accompanying picture of why it visually feels wrong. Note also that in 3D space, the "angle" at which you view the points/line matters a lot. Are you certain you're watching plane $P$ from "above"? If not, visual confirmation may not work.

Comment: Thanks for your time @N.Bach. I narrowed down the problem to a numeric calculus problem. I may close this topic and open one on stackoverlow.

Comment: No problem, good luck with figuring out the rest.